# How to retain value for radio button in form when using GO back in Multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<tr>
<td >
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Masseur" />MASSEUR
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Agent"  />AGENT
</td>
</tr>
```

when coming back to this page using a go back button in next page i want the radio button selected previously to be retained(checked).Since i already have the value i can't use

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="<?php echo ?>"  />
```

Comment: did you hold the value anywhere ??

Comment: 1. If you are posting forms then you can use $_POST variable. 2. Saving into session and using it also an idea, but after processing you have to delete them from session

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman No since i was sending this page directly to the next page based on radio like this :                   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    $filename=$_POST['radio1'].".php";
    header("Location:$filename");
   }

Comment: when you click on browser back button, if you not hold any information in a variable or session or database , you will lost all information .

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman i get what you are saying but even if store it in session how should i retain the value

Comment: Suppose you store all post value in session 
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Masseur" <?= ((isset($_SESSION[radio1])) && ($_SESSION[radio1] =='Masseur') ? 'checjed' : '' >  />MASSEUR

if you store value in session it will word , mean it show previous value

Comment: @Shady7447if the answer is correct then please accept that. Then only others can easy to refer  the ans.Please do it.

Comment: @pranavm.s the answer looks correct but i don't know why its not working for me

Comment: @Shady7447 try to post the or submit the same button while pressing back button to the prev page . the process the post request . And assign the radio value to the corresponding variable. This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1"  value="Masseur" "<?php if(isset($yourValue) && $yourValue=='Masseur' && $yourValue!='AGENT'){ echo 'checked';} ?>"  />MASSEUR

<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Agent"  "<?php if(isset($yourValue) && $yourValue=='AGENT' && $yourValue!='Masseur'){ echo 'checked';} ?>" />AGENT
```

It is working in my case . Please have a try on this may help you.